# Wifi as Bridge & Private Network

Tags: wifi

So I understand that you can configure a PI to act as a bridge - going from wifi to ethernet port, etc.  My question is a bit different - and not sure if I can do it.

At a customer site we have multiple IPADs that access a customer wireless network.  We also have a PI accessing the same wireless network.  The client wants to know if we can make the PI act as our own internal wifi-network (non published SSID) - and have it connect to their WIFI network at the same time.  Basically acting as a wifi-gateway - but not using the ethernet port at all.

Theoretically this seems possible - but it also means the pi probably has to act as DHCP server as well (no big deal).

Thanks

Comment: The viability of this depends much on the number of ipads/the total average volume of traffic you expect to be bridged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Pi an AP with 2 WiFi adapters?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12276/how-to-make-pi-an-ap-with-2-wifi-adapters)

Answer (score 1):

The principle is the same as for a wireless -> Ethernet bridge, you just use a second wifi dongle in client mode in place of the Ethernet connection.